# Cannot fetch array inside a function PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, function, fetch

I can't fetch an array inside a function but I can do it outside of the function. When I fetched it outside the function and echo it out, it prints out 1, but inside the function, using the same fetch array codes and echoing it out, it echos as null. I can tell because the --- symbols echos out, but the number 1 doesn't. I'm confused, because if it worked outside the function, the same code should work inside a function, right? Unless I'm doing something wrong? Please help. Thanks.

```
<?php

include('connect.php');
include('username.php');
//include('functionGet.php');

$boo = $_GET['boo'];
echo "$boo";

function getData($select,$from,$where,$equals){

$fetch = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT acceptedChallenges FROM      
userLogin WHERE username = '$username'"));
$fetch = $fetch['acceptedChallenges'];

echo "---$fetch---";

}

if($boo = 'yes'){

$acceptedChallenges =    
getData("acceptedChallenges","userLogin","username",$username);

$fetch = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT acceptedChallenges FROM    
userLogin WHERE username = '$username'"));
$fetch = $fetch['acceptedChallenges'];

echo "$acceptedChallenges$username$fetch";

//mysql_query("UPDATE userLogin SET openChallenges = '0' WHERE username =   
'$username'");
//mysql_query("UPDATE userLogin SET acceptedChallenges =   
'$acceptedChallenges' WHERE username = '$username'");

}
else{



}
?>
```

Comment: `if($boo === 'yes')`, also, mysql is deprecated use mysqli or pdo

Comment: @Pedro Lobito That's not the problem. The if statements works fine, and it's echoing out the number, which is 1. But inside the function it's not echoing the number, just the --- marks.

Comment: How can the if statement work fine if instead of checking a Boolean value you're assigning to `$boo` the value `yes` ?!

Comment: @wolfpupxd I think Pedro meant that you only have one equals sign instead of two in your if-statement. `$boo = 'yes'` will always be true, since 'yes' can always be assigned to `$boo`. More likely you want to check if `$boo` is 'yes', so you should use a comparison operator `==` instead of an assignment operator `=`

Comment: @PedroLobito, lol.  He means everything still works because he hasn't actually tested it.   `if ($boo = 'yes')` will always return true.

Comment: Did you see this? "$fetch = $fetch['acceptedChallenges'];"

Comment: @Devon ok, that makes more sense!

Comment: @Schlaus That's true. But that still doesn't answer my original question.

Comment: @wolfpupxd before start coding, you should study more how php works, spare some time to read http://www.w3schools.com/php/ or http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php

Answer (score 1):

You're using `$username` in your query, but there's no such variable in your function:

```
function getData($select,$from,$where,$equals){

$fetch = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT acceptedChallenges FROM      
userLogin WHERE username = '$username'"));
$fetch = $fetch['acceptedChallenges'];

echo "---$fetch---";

}
```

In regards to the discussion in comments, here's a clip to demonstrate variable scope:

```
$username = "Testing";

function test1() {
    echo $username;  // Will emit Notice, since $username is undefined
}

function test2() {
    global $username;
    echo $username;  // Will work, but this is bad practice
}

function test3($username) {
    echo $username;  // This is the proper way to do it
}

test1();
test2();
test3($username);
```

You can play with it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6e14d8080d83fdc450df08ec76a7d5bcfa08bfe2).

Comment: It's included in the include('username').

Comment: @wolfpupxd that's not how PHP works. The function `getData` can only see the variables you're passing in to it as arguments.

Comment: @wolfpupxd Here's a nice summary on how variable scopes work in PHP: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_variables.asp

Comment: @Schlaus My god. This is embarrassing. The function didn't work because of scope. I'm going to kill myself now.

Comment: @Schlaus Will it work if I declare $username as public in username.php?

Comment: @wolfpupxd You could use `global $username` inside your function to get access to the variable, but using global variables is very bad practice. Looking at your code, if you just change `$username` to `$equals` inside your function, it should work.

Comment: @Schlaus Thank you so much. And one more question? I can only declare variables public inside a class, right? And to access public variables outside of the class, I just have to type className.variableName, right? Or I have to type global too?

Comment: @wolfpupxd I added a bit more verbose explanation to my answer. And yes, only classes can have public variables (or 'properties' more properly put). To access a public property you use `$instanceOfMyClass->publicProperty`, or `className::$publicProperty` if the property is static.

If you run into further problems you should ask a new question. The PHP manual has a lot of good info on both subjects, and I really recommend giving it a read!

Answer (score 1):

you are passing `$where` instead of `$username` so change

```
 function getData($select,$from,$where,$equals){
```

to

```
 function getData($select,$from,$username,$equals){
```

Comment: $where IS the username I'm passing, and besides, inside the function, I'm not passing ANYTHING yet. I'm just copying and pasting the codes which works below inside the function, and echoing to see if it works inside the function - which it doesn't.

Comment: why do you directly copy and paste? make changes as per your need and run the script. Since you have used $username in the query, so you need to assign some value to that variable..

Answer (score 0):

This code souns very bad:

- Dont eval string with the variable if ouy have the variable echo $boo;
- Don't use eval string ", use non eval ' and concat variables
- Put globales off and escape the variables before query to prevent injection mysql_real_escape
- Do a class to abstract data, not a function
- Use non deprecated connect db functions like mysqli or pdo
- Don't use static funcions to connect, use an instance of the library and his methods, is clear and more simple $db=new Mysqli()
- Don't concat 2 or 3 functions, set the result in a variable and continue  in a next line.
- Iterate the result of fetch with if or while depending you have one or more results, don't get the result directly
- Don't close php tag if you only have php

I suggest:

- Set globales off if you have on in your php (show if on with phpinfo()
- Create a instance of database using PDO library $db=new PDO()...
- Create a class to get database information for everhy entity for example ChallengeObject with a method to get information function get($user)
- Instance the ChallengeObject and pass to the constructor the database connection instance.
- Inside get() function use prepared statements to pass data and prevent injection

  ```
  private databse;

  function __construct($database) {
      $this->databse=$databse;
  }

  function get($user) {
      $sql='SELECT acceptedChallenges FROM userLogin WHERE username = :user';
      $this->database->prepare($sql)
      $this->database->bindParam(":user",$user,'PDO::INT_VALUE);
      $this->database->execute();
      if ($user=$this->databse->fetch()) {
        return $user;
      }
      return false;
  }



  <?php
  $database=new PDO(...);

  $challengeObject=new ChallengeObject($database);
  $user=$challengeObject->get($_POST['boo']);
  if ($user!=false) {
     echo "Authenticated successfull";
  }
  ```